# ¿Como comparo dos palabras de dos cadenas diferentes?

Tags: java

Solo quiero comparar la primera palabra de dos strings si dan igual o no...

Ejemplo:

```
String1="No puedo comparar"
String2="Si puedo comparar"
```

Tendría que dar **falso** ya que no son igual el `SI` y el `NO`.

```
String1="Si puedo comparar"
String2="Si podre comparar"
```

Tendría que dar verdadero ya que son iguales el `Si` y el `SI`.

---

Tiene que pedir el valor del string por teclado, entonces esta es la parte del código que tengo, pero cuando lo ejecuto siempre me da que son iguales así escriba cosas diferentes, ¿qué esta mal?:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class comparacion{
    String cadena1=("");
    String cadena2=("");

    String cadena1Array[]=cadena1.split(" ");
    String c=cadena1Array[0];
    String cadena2Array[]=cadena2.split(" ");
    String c2=cadena1Array[0];
}


import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        comparacion q=new comparacion();


        System.out.println("Ingrese primera frase");
        //llamado a la clase comparacion
        Scanner read=new Scanner(System.in);
        //Metodo de lectura de la variable cadebna 1 
        q.cadena1=read.nextLine();


        System.out.println("Ingrese segunda frase");
        Scanner read2=new Scanner(System.in);
        q.cadena2=read2.nextLine();

        //Quitar equals y comparar dos palabras iguales.
        if(q.c.equals(q.c2)){
            System.out.println(q.c);
            System.out.println(q.c2);
            System.out.println("Eureka");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Quieres hacerlo en java, o javascript?

Comment: Por el código que puso en la respuesta, es Java. Reetiqueté la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Para separar la primera palabra de tu cadena podrías usar la funcion `split()` de javascript, luego comprobar si una cadena existe en ambas palabras.

Para comprobar que una cadena existe existe en otra puedes usar la función `contains()` de javascript.

De esa manera tendrías un script como el siguiente:

```js
var a = "Si puedo comparar";
var b = "Si podre comparar";

var c = a.split(" ");
var d = b.split(" ");

if(c[0].includes("Si") && d[0].includes("Si")){
  console.log(c[0]+" "+d[0]);
  console.log("Bien palabras son iguales");
}else{
  console.log(c[0]+" "+d[0]);
  console.log("Mal palabras son diferentes");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Podría Utilizar el método [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) y luego comparar con la posición 0 que sería la primera palabra antes de un espacio en blanco en una cadena

```
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Primera Frase");
   String cadena1= scan.next();
   System.out.println("Segunda Frase");
   String cadena2= scan.next();

   /* Teniendo en Cuenta Mayusculas ni Minusculas */
   System.out.println(cadena1.split(" ")[0].equals(cadena2.split(" ")[0]));

  /* Sin tener en cuenta Mayusculas ni Minusculas */
   System.out.println(cadena1.split(" ")
    [0].toLowerCase().equals(cadena2.split(" ")[0].toLowerCase()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Las respuestas anteriores ya son correctas, te muestro otra forma de hacerlo aunque yo siempre utilizo la función split() ( es faster, harder & stronger);

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(TuString, el delimitador);
 //StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("hola que pasa", " ");

   while(st.hasMoreTokens() && "condicion booleana si quieres romper el bucle") {
       String primerPalabra= st.nextToken();
       if(primeraPalabra.equals("lo que sea");
   }
```

y te recomiendo echarle un ojo a StringUtils de apache 
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer esto se puede hacer con una comparación normal dentro de un if:

```
if(String1 == String2){
    //Sentencia a ejecutar 
}
```

Esto daría una comparación entre las dos variables pero si en dado caso las variables serian:

> String1 = "Si puedo comparar";
>
> String2 = "SI PUEDO COMPARAR";

En este caso ya los String serian diferentes y no haría la comparación, para asegurar que se hagan bien las comparaciones se pueden usar los métodos:

> toUpperCase() --> Convierte la cadena a mayúscula
>
> toLowerCase() --> Convierte la cadena a minúscula

Ahora la comparación seria así:

```
if(String1.toUpperCase() == String2.toUpperCase()){
        //Sentencia a ejecutar 
}
```

Pero hay otro caso, este es cuando tus variables sean las siguientes:

> String1 = "   SI PUEDO COMPARAR  ";
>
> String2 = "SI PUEDO COMPARAR";

Ahí los valores son las palabras son las mismas pero con los  espacios ya el string toma diferente valor, para este caso se utilizaría el siguiente método:

> trim() -->Quita los espacios al inicio y al final

Quedando la comparación de la siguiente manera:

```
if(String1.trim().toUpperCase() == String2.trim().toUpperCase()){
      //Sentencia a ejecutar 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

prueba asi

```
"hola mundo"=="hola mundo"
```

para comparar se utiliza el operador binario "==" 
ojo: el operador de asignacion es "=" no confundas

Comment: Por lo que entendí de la pregunta, quiere comparar sólo la primera palabra.